# Installing existing Ubuntu 11.04 (guest) in VirtualBox on Windows 7 (host)

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, grub2, ubuntu-11.04, xorg.conf

I have successfully installed existing Ubuntu 10.10 on Windows 7 host as explained in [this blog post](http://kirilligum.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/run-existing-linux-ubuntu-10-10-partition-in-virtualbox-under-host-windows-7-system-on-thinkpad-x201t/). Everything worked.

I did a clean install of Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Then I tried to follow the same steps and install existing Ubuntu 11.04 in Windows 7's VB. It didn't work well. VB does not grab the mouse. It also gives an error after grub "error: hd0 out of disk" and asks to press any  key. After the error it boots into the login screen, but as I said it doesn't grab the mouse. I tried installing VB guest additions. That didn't help either.   I also couldn't find xorg.conf file in /etc/x11 on Ubuntu 11.04

Has anyone had success with this?

Comment: when i do 'grub> ls' i get "(hd0) (hd0,msdos7) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)"

Comment: "error: hd0 out of disk" doesn't appear if i do manual boot using a command line "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Express Boot to the Most Recent Kernel". i use (hd0,5) or sda5. after ubuntu loads to the log in screen i still cannot move the mouse

Comment: In the link you gave there seem to be solution provided for the 'out of disk' error: "with VirtualBox-4.0.8-71778-Win, i got an error that hd0 is full, press any key…   i ignorred it and pressed any key. then gives an error that looks smtn like “error ahci-0-0 existing verr_access_denied” i had to go into vm’s settings>storage> SATA controller> check use host i/o cache.  note  currently i use ubuntu 11.04 with guest edition installed from apt-get", have you tried this?

Comment: What size did you make your VB drive? Maybe I am oversimplifying but "out of disk" appears pretty straightforward. You may have a new kernel that is running your /boot volume out of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the newer version of VB worked. the link has an updated solution

Comment: it's an old question. I just wanted to close it.

Answer (score 0):

I have numerous Ubuntu VMs running on my Windows 7 desktop. One of them has several months of uptime (greater than the uptime of the Windows 7 host). I use these for software development running Eclipse, running unit tests and running Selenium Firefox functional tests.

Most of the Ubuntu VMs are Lucid desktop or Lucid server but the last 4 were Precise Pangolin desktops. I have never encountered problems like you describe. Basically, create a VM, I open Settings and review everything, then I run through the normal install from CD (actually from a .iso file which has been checked with the published checksums) and I use expanding filesystem, usually set to 32G even though I only need a fraction of that. After the Ubuntu install and reboot, I always install the Additions from the VB Devices menu. Only after rebooting again, do I install special tools and things like OpenSSH Server, vim, Oracle Java.

Did you do your install from a physical CD? If so, there may be I/O errors that corrupted your install.

How much spare hard drive space do you have in Windows 7 on the disk that holds the virtual Ubuntu hard drive? Even expandable virtual drives can't make disk space out of thin air.

Your reference to more than one hard drive device puzzles me. Are you using multiple virtual drives to practice administering something like LVM? If the virtual machine is just there because you need to run some Linux software, then I recommend that you always define only one virtual hard drive, and make it a SATA drive. Then when you install Ubuntu, tell it to use the entire hard drive.

Also, if you don't have a specific technical reason to use 11.04, then I strongly suggest that you install Ubuntu 12.04 instead. That one has long term support which means that you don't have to worry about the repositories going away.

If you are trying to boot from another disk partition, I believe you need to use the Windows pathname such as \Device\Harddisk0\Partition2 and you need to create a VMDK file which contains the configuration and points Virtualbox to the raw partition.

You can't do this in the GUI. You need to run `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk` to create the special VMDK file.

I did this successfully with Windows XP a few years ago but I don't know if it is still possible with Windows 7 and newer Ubuntu.

Comment: perhaps I should have been more clear. By existing, I mean an installation of ubuntu on the other partition of my hard drive. I have a dual boot with win7 and ubuntu.